# Making an image rotate and change it across multiple devices

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, jquery-mobile

I just made my first web app and i'm trying to make it look cool(college project).
I'm using JQM and I'm trying to use an image as the background.
Now a few logical problems came up and I need some assistance.

I have no idea how to re-size the image directly to fit cross-platform  devices, Including orientation mode making it fit right on almost-every screen.

Thanks!

Heres the CSS code:

```
#home {
    background: url(Images/image.jpg) !important;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position:center;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-size:100%
}
.ui-page, .ui-content, .ui-btn {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `background-size: cover` (crops image to fill background) or `background-size: contain` (shows complete image, letterboxed if necessary).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: What happened instead?

Comment: Nothing , stayed the same as an static image background

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem online somewhere, so we can take a look at it in practice?

Comment: I'm trying but it doesnt really work the same since I'm using JQM